# How to compare Two Complex Objects?

Tags: c#

I want to write a `List` on my own.
So I have a class `List` and a class `ListItem`.
What I now want to do is to create differente classes, for example the class `car`. I would like to deduce the class `car` from the class ListItem so that I can create a `List` of cars. 
Now the Class `List` shall have different methodes like the one C# gives you.
I wrote an Add and a Count methode and both work.
Here comes the tricky part... I want to write a Funktion to Find an Item in the List. The problem is that I can´t just compare them because 1. I don´t know what the Objekt will look like and what members it will have.
2. I don´t want to compare the characteristics of the class ListItem because they aren´t relevant to the real Object, they are just relevant for the List.

My Idea is, to Create a List Class for each object so in my example it would be a `carList` which is deduced from the List Class. This way I could write a Methode that would know what to compare because it would know the ListItem Object. Now I don´t want to create a list class for every Object I want to have a list of. There must be a different way sice c# also gives you the same list class.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question was "Can anyone help?" - the answer is plainly "Yes, someone can help". But please share what you have to far, helping yourself by making helping you easier.

Comment: @fubo I don´t know what you mean... Of course I give the object to search for as an overload to my function!

Comment: Can you give us a proposed method signature for the `Find` method? Will there also be a `Contains` method.

Comment: Also, why not just use the provided generic `List<T>` Class? You'll sidestep most of your issues trivially.

Comment: @SWeko may be it's a homework ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should override `Equals` (inherited from `object`) on your `Car`-class:

```
class car
{
    public override bool Equals(object other) {
        var o = other as car;
        if ( o == null ) return false;

        if this.myProperty = o.myProperty return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

The list will then use this implenentation for detecting if two cars are equal. Within your `Find`-method you can now simply call for every item in the list if it equals the searched one:

```
if (currentItemInList.Equals(searchItem)) // ...
```

EDIT: When implementing `Equals` for any class you should always also implement `GetHashCode` in case that objects of your class are stored in hashed containers like `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. If you want to read further see [MSDN for GetHashCode and Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: If you write the whole list implementation yourself you can actually name the comparison methods any way you like, because it's you who calls them. If it could happen that your objects end up in generic containers though you should probably implement `IEquatable<T>`, in addition to `object.Equals()`. Cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. You should for sure also implement `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Of course you´re right, however I tried to keep it simple. I added the HashCode also.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that `GetHashCode()` is only important for Dictionaries and possibly other hashed containers, but not for general equality tests.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Nope, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden for why implementing getHasCode also

Comment: A tiny comment: if you're going to use `is` then cast, you may as well use `as` then check for `null`.

Comment: But Marc Gravell's answer says exactly that: *"if your item will be used as a key in a dictionary..."* or other containers which use a hash code. `GetHashCode()` is by no means called whenever `Equals()` is called. That would be costly because computing a hash code can be just as expensive as testing for equality. It's just that the hashed containers use the hash code for quick retrieval, but for that must rely on the hash code's logical connection to equality.

Comment: ... you're almost there - but you made it cast instead of using `as`, which can result in an `InvalidCastException` for non-`Car` instances. I've edited your answer to resolve this.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Oh dear, ya you´re right, sorry. This happens when coding faster then thinking.

Comment: `Equals(object)` vs. `Equals(type)` has nothing to do with `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider oops, whrong post, ya you´re right. Looking for the correct one. Here is it: "It is recommended that any class that overrides Equals also override System.Object.GetHashCode."

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the post so that the role of `GetHashCode()` is clarified.